# formalization of partial function for counting

Tags: counting, coq

I need assistance in defining axioms for partial functions in total function theory that is available in [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/assumptions.html).
Specifically, I'm looking for a constructive definition of a partial function that includes a constructor for obtaining a partial function from a smaller finite domain.

My use case involves formalizing the problem of counting the number of mappings from the set $\{0, 1, 2\}$ to $\{0, 1, \ldots, 4\}$. This can be represented as the size of the set of all such functions
.Additionally, I am open to including the [function extensionality axiom](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality.html#functional_extensionality_dep).

I formalized multiplication principles and solved the number of permutations problem using it.

assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question might be better asked in [proofassistants.SE].

Comment: There are $5^3 = 125$ such functions. You cannot literally mean that that is the problem you're trying to formalize. What is the *real* problem you'd like formalized? By the way, trying to formalize partial functions is the wrong way to approach this.